# If $|g| = k$ then $|g^m| = k / $lcm$(k, m)$

Tags: group-theory

Here $g$ is in a group $G$.
The only proof I got uses the concept of cyclic groups, but this wasn't introduced yet. How can I prove it in a simpler way?

Comment: The concept of a cyclic group is probably easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** The result is
$$|g^m|=\frac{k}{\color{red}{\gcd(k,m)}}.$$

Let $|g^m|=t$, then $(g^m)^t=e$. This means $k | tm$ ($\because$ $|g|=k$). Consider
$$ak=tm \qquad \text{ for some } a \in \Bbb{N}.$$
Then,
$$ak=tm \implies a\,\,\frac{k}{\gcd(m,k)}=t\,\,\frac{m}{\gcd(m,k)}.$$
Since $\gcd\left(\frac{m}{\gcd(m,k)}, \frac{k}{\gcd(m,k)}\right)=1$. This means $\frac{k}{\gcd(m,k)}$ divides $t$.

Since $t$ is the order so it has to be the *least* positive integer with *this* property. Thus
$$t=\frac{k}{\gcd(m,k)}$$